# Get Azure resource by id with Azure Python SDK

Tags: azure-sdk-python

I'd like to get/check azure resource by `ID`

```
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
resource_client.resources.check_existence_by_id(
'/subscriptions/<any_subscr>/resourceGroups/random_group'
'/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/test_vm', 
api_version='2017-12-01')
```

fails with:

```
ClientRequestError: Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /subscriptions/<any_subscr>/resourceGroups/random_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/test_vm?api-version=2017-12-01 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 503 error responses',))
```

`api_version` was taken from another error. If I try to run same command with `api_version=resource_client.api_version` and get:

```
CloudError: Azure Error: NoRegisteredProviderFound
Message: No registered resource provider found for location 'eastus2' and API version '2017-05-10' for type 'virtualMachines'. The supported api-versions are '2015-05-01-preview, 2015-06-15, 2016-03-30, 2016-04-30-preview, 2016-08-30, 2017-03-30, 2017-12-01'. The supported locations are 'eastus, eastus2, westus, centralus, northcentralus, southcentralus, northeurope, westeurope, eastasia, southeastasia, japaneast, japanwest, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, brazilsouth, southindia, centralindia, westindia, canadacentral, canadaeast, westus2, westcentralus, uksouth, ukwest, koreacentral, koreasouth'.
```

but `.get_by_id()` with same `api_version` works fine.

Is there something wrong with `check_existence_by_id`?

Comment: `az resource show --id '/subscriptions/<any_subscr>/resourceGroups/random_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/test-vm' ` 
also works as expected. without any `api_version` specification

Answer (score 1):

`check_existence_by_id` is a thin wrapper on the RestAPI, that more or less just provide authentication easy. The API version you need to provide is a indeed the one linked to the Resource Type you want (if your case `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines`).

You can get this information using the CLI and `az provider list` or the SDK with the `providers` attribute of your resource client.

Note for your remark about CLI not needing an ApiVersion, if you execute the command in `--debug` mode, you'll see that the CLI is indeed doing a `az provider list` under the hood after parsing the resource ID to get the correct ApiVersion to use.

(I work in the Azure SDK for Python team)

Answer (score 0):

```
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

# Acquire a credential object using CLI-based authentication.
credential = AzureCliCredential()

# Obtain the management object for resources.
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
resource_client.resources.get_by_id(resource_id,api_version='2019-08-01')
```

Took me a while to find it.