# "Dereference" a sub-resource in the Azure Python SDK return value

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

I would like to retrieve the public IP address associated with a given network interface. I need to do something like

```
client = NetworkManagementClient(...)
interface = client.network_interfaces.get('rg', 'nic-name')
ip_config_id = interface[0].public_ip_address.id
ip_config = some_magic(ip_config_id)  # What goes here?
return ip_config.ip_address
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295700/how-do-i-get-instance-id-name-from-public-ip-address-of-vm-in-azure-via-python-s) suggests that in order to implement the `some_magic` routine, I should parse the ID (by splitting on slashes) and call `client.public_ip_addresses.get()`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032428/get-azure-resource-by-id-with-azure-python-sdk) indicates that I can call `resource_client.resources.get_by_uid`, but that doesn't return a `PublicIPAddress` object (I know I can call `as_dict` on it and get the data that way).

Is there a way to get an object of the appropriate type (in this case `PublicIPAddress`) from an object's ID in Azure (without manually parsing the ID)?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer:). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to check it out; I was busy with other parts of my project. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have solved my main issue, which was getting the IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Due to this issue: [public_ip_address method within NetworkManagementClient will not return values](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10735#), we cannot fetch the ip address from `PublicIPAddress`.

So currently, you can use any other workaround, For example:

```
myip = client.public_ip_addresses.get(" resource_group_name","public_ip_address_name")
print(myip.ip_address)
```

---

You can change this line of code `ip_config_id = interface[0].public_ip_address.id` to something like `my_public_ip_address = interface.ip_configurations[0].public_ip_address`, then the return type is `PublicIPAddress`.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, while you're correct that it's the correct type, when I inspect the value of `i.ip_configurations[0].public_ip_address.ip_address` it is None. However, when I get the IP address from `client.public_ip_addresses.get(...)`, it gives me the correct IP address.

Comment: @JoeyMarianer, it's really weird. When I open `fiddler`, I can see everything including the `public_ip_address` is there. I need some time to figure it out and update to you later.

Comment: @JoeyMarianer, it's actually a bug in the sdk. If you open fiddler, you can see all the data  are returned correctly. Some people already raised [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/10735#) in github to track it. And before it's fixed, you should use any workaround to fetch the public_ip_address.

Comment: Updated my answer with this bug. And if the answer is helpful, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks:).

Comment: @IvanGlasenberg Hey Ivan thank you for your help can I ask how you managed to get this panel the panel indicating attributes of the objects